# When creating service method what's the difference between module.service and module.factory

Tags: angularjs

I don't know what is the best practice and what I should use.

What is the difference between below two methods?

```
module.service(..);
```

and

```
module.factory(..);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js: service vs provide vs factory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provide-vs-factory)

Comment: @MarkRajcok it is but the answer here has better examples

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is a great google group post about this from Pawel Kozlowski:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/hVrkvaHGOfc/idEaEctreMYJ

Quoted from Powel:

> in fact $provide.provider, $provide.factory and $provide.service are 
>   more or less the same thing in the sense that all of them are 
>   blueprints / instructions for creating object instances (those 
>   instances are then ready to be injected into collaborators).
>
> $provide.provider is the most spohisticated method of registering 
>   blueprints, it allows you to have a complex creation function and 
>   configuration options.
>
> $provide.factory is a simplified version of $provide.provider when you
>   don't need to support configuration options but still want to have a 
>   more sophisticated creation logic.
>
> $provide.service is for cases where the whole creation logic boils 
>   down to invoking a constructor function.
>
> So, depending on the complexity of your construction logic you would 
>   choose one of $provide.provider, $provide.factory and $provide.service
>   but in the end what you are going to get is a new instance.

Here is the accompanying fiddle to demonstrate (from the thread):  http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/PxdSP/14/

And the code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//service style, probably the simplest one
myApp.service('helloWorldFromService', function() {
    this.sayHello = function() {
        return "Hello, World!"
    };
});

//factory style, more involved but more sophisticated
myApp.factory('helloWorldFromFactory', function() {
    return {
        sayHello: function() {
            return "Hello, World!"
        }
    };
});

//provider style, full blown, configurable version     
myApp.provider('helloWorld', function() {

    this.name = 'Default';

    this.$get = function() {
        var name = this.name;
        return {
            sayHello: function() {
                return "Hello, " + name + "!"
            }
        }
    };

    this.setName = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };
});

//hey, we can configure a provider!            
myApp.config(function(helloWorldProvider){
    helloWorldProvider.setName('World');
});


function MyCtrl($scope, helloWorld, helloWorldFromFactory, helloWorldFromService) {

    $scope.hellos = [
        helloWorld.sayHello(),
        helloWorldFromFactory.sayHello(),
        helloWorldFromService.sayHello()];
}
```

Comment: +1 There are several more popular questions/answers on the service vs factory (vs provider) concept (and I have gone over them a couple of times), but this is by far the most clear explanation. Would have saved me quite some time, had I found it sooner :)

Comment: what about functions that have dependencies? Can you use the DI notation? `myApp.service('helloWorldFromService', ['$resource', function($resource) {...}`?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following service.

```
angular.module("myModule", [])
.service("thingCountingService", function() {
    var thingCount = 0;
    this.countThing = function() { thingCount++; }
    this.getNumThings = function() { return thingCount; }
});
```

If you had an app, in which a variety of controllers, views, etc, all want to contribute to one general count of things, the above service works.

But what if each app wants to keep its own tally of things?

In that case, a singleton service would not work since it can only keep track of all of them. However, a factory lets you create a new service every time you want to start a new counter.

```
angular.module("myModule", [])
.factory("thingCountingServiceFactory", function() {
    var thingCount = 0;
    this.countThing = function() { thingCount++; }
    this.getNumThings = function() { return thingCount; }
});
```

With the above factory, you can call `new thingCountingServiceFactory()` at any time and get a new `thingCountingService` set to `0`

Comment: What do you mean by - "But what if each app wants to keep its own tally of things?" I have a single app and everyone too.