# Syncing data between controllers through a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008908/how-can-i-pass-variables-between-controllers-in-angularjs), my understanding is that I should be using services to pass data between controllers.

However, as seen in [my example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VP4d5/1/), I am having trouble listening to changes to my service when it is modified across controllers.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope, App) {
        $scope.status = App.data.status;
        $scope.$watch('App.data.status', function() {
            $scope.status = App.data.status;
        });
})
    .controller('Ctrl2', function ($scope, App) {
        $scope.status = App.data.status;
        $scope.$watch('status', function() {
            App.data.status = $scope.status;
        });
})
    .service('App', function () {
        this.data = {};
        this.data.status = 'Good';
});
```

In my example, I am trying to subscribe to `App.data.status` in `Ctrl1`, and I am trying to publish data from `Ctrl1` to `App`. However, if you try to change the input box in the `div` associated with `Ctrl2`, the text does not change across the controller boundary across to `Ctrl1`.

Comment: It looks like you meant to say "publish data from **Ctrl2** to App".

Answer (score 10):

http://jsfiddle.net/VP4d5/2/

Here's an updated fiddle.  Basically if you're going to share the same data object between two controllers from a service you just need to use an object of some sort aside from a string or javascript primitive.  In this case I'm just using a regular Object {} to share the data between the two controllers.

The JS

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope, App) {
        $scope.localData1 = App.data;
})
    .controller('Ctrl2', function ($scope, App) {
        $scope.localData2 = App.data;
})
    .service('App', function () {
        this.data = {status:'Good'};
});
```

The HTML

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <div> Ctrl1 Status is: {{status}}
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="localData1.status" />
    </div>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl2">Ctrl2 Status is: {{status}}
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="localData2.status" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Nothing wrong with using a service here but if the only purpose is to have a shared object across the app then I think using .value makes a bit more sense.  If this service will have functions for interacting with endpoints and the data be sure to use angular.copy to update the object properties instead of using = which will replace the service's local reference but won't be reflected in the controllers.

http://jsfiddle.net/VP4d5/3/

The modified JS using .value

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope, sharedObject) {
        $scope.localData1 = sharedObject;
})
    .controller('Ctrl2', function ($scope, sharedObject) {
        $scope.localData2 = sharedObject;
})
.value("sharedObject", {status:'Awesome'});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful... however, I am still having the issue where if the service variable is updated, the controller doesn't know about it. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VP4d5/4/. After a timeout, the service variable is updated, the controllers won't know to update until I click on the div (I added an ng-click).

Comment: If you are using something async outside of angular you need to call $apply to cause angular to run the digest cycle, if you really just want a timeout you can use $timeout service which will do the call to $apply for you, alternatively I have an example here where I injected the $rootScope, and it seems calling $apply() on that is good enough http://jsfiddle.net/VP4d5/5/  Basically $http $timeout and other angular services automatically do this for you but in some cases you need to integrate third party stuff then calling $apply yourself is necessary to trigger an update.

Comment: Thanks for angular.copy

Answer (score 6):

I agree with @shaunhusain, but I think that you would be better off using a factory instead of a service:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope, App) {
        $scope.localData1 = App.data;
    })
    .controller('Ctrl2', function ($scope, App) {
        $scope.localData2 = App.data;
    })
    .factory('App', function () {
        var sharedObj = {
            data : {
                status: 'Good'
            }
        };

        return sharedObj;
    });
```

Here are some information that might help you understand the differences between a `factory` and a `service`: [When creating service method what's the difference between module.service and module.factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565105/angularjs-what-is-difference-of-creating-service-method-between-module-service-a)