# Initialize $scope variables for multiple controllers - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have 3 controllers that do similar tasks:

- **PastController** queries an API for past system outages.
- **CurrentController** queries an API for current system outages
- **FutureController** queries an API for future system outages

They are each unique (despite their similar functions). However, they all begin by defining the same `$scope` variables:

```
app.controller("PastController", function ($scope) {
   $scope.Outages = "";
   $scope.loading = 0;
   $scope.nothing = 0;
   $scope.error = 0;
   //--- code continues ---//
});

app.controller("CurrentController", function ($scope) {
   $scope.Outages = "";
   $scope.loading = 0;
   $scope.nothing = 0;
   $scope.error = 0;
   //--- code continues ---//
});

app.controller("FutureController", function ($scope) {
   $scope.Outages = "";
   $scope.loading = 0;
   $scope.nothing = 0;
   $scope.error = 0;
   //--- code continues ---//
});
```

Can I use a service or factory to initialize those variables in one place rather than repeating the code?

Comment: this is a perfect example to implement also some inheritance between controllers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't test the code, but this is my idea if you want to work with services, hope it works.

Create the service first:

```
    app.service('systemService', function(){

     // initialize object first
    this.info = {}; 
    this.initialize = function(){
      //  properties initialization
      this.info.Outages = "";
      this.info.loading = 0;
      this.info.nothing = 0;
      this.info.error = 0;

      return this.info;
    }

    this.fooFunction = function() {
        return "Hello!"
    };

  });
```

In the end, you have to inject the created service into controllers correctly and call the initialize function from service:

```
app.controller("PastController",['$scope','systemService', function ($scope, systemService) {
$scope.info = systemService.initialize();
$scope.fooFunction = systemService.fooFunction();
}]);
```

... and set so in each controller.

Comment: Np,  I'm glad that I could help :-)

Comment: @SidBhalke , sorry for late response. The idea is the same: just create another function in service and bind it to one $scope variable. I edited my answer, to see more details, here is a good post on this thema : [http://stackoverflow.com/a/16566144/4064237]